# Start a screen session inside LXD-managed container

Tags: lxc, gnu-screen, lxd

I'd like to start a `screen` session inside an LXD-managed container so that I could detach running processes and maybe re-attach in the future when I want to check on their status.

I tried to attach to the container running

```
$ lxc exec my-ubuntu -- /bin/bash
```

and then start a session with `screen -x`, but I get the following error:

```
Must be connected to a terminal.
```

I can see that many people have had a similar problem when trying to initiate `screen` from `ssh`, but I couldn't apply the suggested solution to my case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For LXD using

```
lxc exec my-ubuntu -- sh -c "exec >/dev/tty 2>/dev/tty </dev/tty && /usr/bin/screen -s /bin/bash"
```

or

```
lxc exec my-ubuntu -- sh -c "exec >/dev/tty 2>/dev/tty </dev/tty && /usr/bin/screen -x"
```

or with any other `screen` switch.

---

The same for Docker
**;)**

```
docker run -it my-ubuntu sh -c "exec >/dev/tty 2>/dev/tty </dev/tty && /usr/bin/screen -s /bin/bash"
```

Comment: Terrific. But how can I then work with `screen` the way I normally do, monitor which sessions are running and re-attach to a specific one?

Comment: I don't understand. In the same way as before. E.g. using `-R`.

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: Well, I would normally do `screen -x`, but trying `lxc exec my-ubuntu -- sh -c "exec >/dev/tty 2>/dev/tty </dev/tty && /usr/bin/screen -x` doesn't work, and neither does `lxc exec my-ubuntu -- sh -c "exec >/dev/tty 2>/dev/tty </dev/tty && /usr/bin/screen -r <pid>.tty.my-ubuntu"`. Nor can I do `screen -x` from within bash in the container.

Comment: What's about `-R`

Comment: I should specify: the reason `... screen -x` fails is because I get `There are several suitable screens on:` followed by a list of sessions. Same with `screen -R`.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask a new question for this problem. :) seems to be a little bit complicated.

Comment: There aren't any answers there, but I'd like to mention that I did open a new question regarding this issue [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/716106/142526). I also suggested a walk-around on that question.

Comment: @JonathanY. just run script /dev/null and then run screen.

Answer (score -1):

For me, the simple solution was to start screen on the host instead of in the container.

```
user@localhost:~$ screen
user@localhost:~$ lxc-attach -n yourcontainer
root@container:~# ./start-gameserver.sh
root@container:~# #Use "Ctrl+A:sessionname mygame<Enter>" to set a screen name
root@container:~# #and use the usual "Ctrl+A,D" to disconnect from screen
user@localhost:~$ screen -ls
There is a screen on:
    25418.mygame    (04/15/2019 11:41:56 PM)    (Detached)
user@localhost:~$ screen -r mygame
root@container:~# #etc.
```