# Working with screen sessions in LXD-managed containers

Tags: lxc, gnu-screen, lxd

I have been trying to attach and detach `screen` sessions in LXD-managed containers; initially, I wasn't able to even start one, but that problem [was answered here](https://askubuntu.com/q/716028/142526).

However, being able to start a session, then detach it, isn't sufficient. To work with `screen` sessions, one must be able to re-attach to a certain session.

I can initiate a session with

```
lxc exec my-ubuntu -- sh -c "exec >/dev/tty 2>/dev/tty </dev/tty && /usr/bin/screen -s /bin/bash"
```

but then, when I issue

```
lxc exec my-ubuntu -- sh -c "exec >/dev/tty 2>/dev/tty </dev/tty && /usr/bin/screen -x"
```

either nothing at all happens (I just get another command line) or, if I've issued the first command more than once, I get `There are several suitable screens on:` followed by a list of sessions, and a suggestion to re-attach to them with `"screen [-d] -r [pid.]tty.host"`. However, that also fails silently. I've also tried to issue

```
lxc exec my-ubuntu -- sh -c "exec >/dev/tty 2>/dev/tty </dev/tty && /bin/bash"
```

and then `screen -x` from the resulting terminal, to no avail.

What can I do?

**EDIT**:
If I use the last command to get a terminal inside my container `my-ubuntu`, I can initiate `screen` sessions just typing `screen`, and detach them with `CTRL-a` followed by `d`. However, `screen -x` then fails silently just as described above, and if I try `CTRL-a` followed by `n` from within a session, it reports `no other window.`

Comment: I'd like to mention that one way around the entire issue is to open the screen on the host, before attaching to the container. Unless you have multiple levels of nested containers, there aren't many disadvantages to that approach that I can see.

Comment: another workaround: connect to container via ssh, even though it's local.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest:-

```
lxc exec <container> --mode=interactive -- bash
```

Comment: I must apologize for not being in a position to test the suggestion anymore.

Comment: No problem..    You might also want to look at my SSH to specific Container gateway/jump setup..

https://github.com/Dweller/lxd-ssh-gateway